# Python pexpect how to get linux command line text from raw output

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, pexpect

I have seen many other examples and non of them cover what I want to do that I can find. I use Pexpect to run an ssh command (I know there is pxssh but it doesn't do everything I need). I get terminal output that is

```
'\r\r\n\x1b]0;user@gateway: ~\x07user@gateway:~$'
```

when I print this string it displays corrrectly

```
user@gateway:~$
```

How can I process this into the same text I see on the screen. I tried re-directing the standard output  of print, but its still had the other escape text. I tried examples of using regex to filter out VT-100 commands but then it still had user@gateway twice. I just want the same text that is normally displayed to the user. Any insight is really helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the prompt string meaning. Explained using a triple-quoted string below:

```
promptRaw = '\r\r\n\x1b]0;user@gateway: ~\x07user@gateway:~$'

'''
promptRaw explanation:

Characters in promptRaw     Meaning               ( Format )
-----------------------     -------               ----------
\r\r\n                      CR CR LF              ( <string> )
\x1b]0;user@gateway: ~\x07  Icon and Window Title ( ESC ] 0 ; <string> BEL )
user@gateway:~$             prompted text         ( <string> )

'''

print(promptRaw.__repr__())

promptStr = promptRaw.split('\x07')[-1]

print(promptStr.__repr__())
```

**Output**: `.\SO\61416565.py`

```
'\r\r\n\x1b]0;user@gateway: ~\x07user@gateway:~$'
'user@gateway:~$'
```

Comment: Hmm so the answer is "build your own vt-100" processor.... I basically did that after I gave up a long time ago.

Comment: Then, [you should answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)!